# Verilog waveform of inputs is identical, however, output is different

Tags: verilog

I'm currently trying to implement an up/down counter in Verilog with dataflow modeling. While trying to add a limit to the counter (so that the counter will reset to the appropriate value when the limit is reached) I stumbled into an error. Even though the waveforms of clear_q, clear, and clear_s are the same, likewise the waveforms of preset_q, preset, and preset_s are the same, the behaviors of Q, R, and S are different, notably Q is different from R and S.

[Picture of Waveforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyZJ9.png)

Of note, the rising edge of the three clear signals is not aligned with the falling edge of the clock, however, Q going from 0 to F is aligned with the rising edge of the three clear signals.

From the code, it is clear that the only difference between clear_q and clear_s, and preset_q and preset_s, is the simple inclusion of "& 1'b1". The only way that Q would go to F from 0 is if preset_q goes low and clear_q goes high momentarily, however from the waveform preset_q stays high.

The purpose of the "& 1'b1" is to temporarily simulate the equality checker commented out.

What exactly is wrong with the "& 1'b1" or is there another issue at hand?

limited_ud_counter.v

```
module limited_ud_counter(input clk, preset, clear, up, input[3:0] limit, output[3:0] Q);
  //wire[3:0] n;
  wire[3:0] Q, R, S;
  wire e, preset_p, clear_p;

  // assign n[0] = Q[0] ^ limit[0];
  // assign n[1] = Q[1] ^ limit[1];
  // assign n[2] = Q[2] ^ limit[2];
  // assign n[3] = Q[3] ^ limit[3];
  // assign e = !(n[0] | n[1] | n[2] | n[3]);

  assign e = 0;

  //(preset & clear & (!(e & up))) | (preset & !clear);
  //(preset & clear & !(e & (!up))) | (clear & !preset);

  assign preset_q = ((preset & clear) & 1'b1) | (preset & !clear);
  assign clear_q = ((preset & clear) & 1'b1) | (clear & !preset);

  assign preset_s = ((preset & clear)) | (preset & !clear);
  assign clear_s = ((preset & clear)) | (clear & !preset);

  //Q not showing expected behavior
  up_down_counter udc0(clk, preset_q, clear_q, up, Q);
  //R showing expected behavior
  up_down_counter udc1(clk, preset, clear, up, R);
  //S also showing expected behavior
  up_down_counter udc2(clk, preset_s, clear_s, up, S);

endmodule;
```

up_down_counter.v

```
module up_down_counter(input clk, preset, clear, up, output[3:0] Q);
  wire[2:0] jk_up, jk_down, jk;
  wire[3:0] Q_bar;

  assign jk_up[0] = Q[0] & up;
  assign jk_down[0] = Q_bar[0] & (!up);
  assign jk[0] = jk_up[0] | jk_down[0];

  assign jk_up[1] = Q[1] & jk_up[0];
  assign jk_down[1] = Q_bar[1] & jk_down[0];
  assign jk[1] = jk_up[1] | jk_down[1];

  assign jk_up[2] = Q[2] & jk_up[1];
  assign jk_down[2] = Q_bar[2] & jk_down[1];
  assign jk[2] = jk_up[2] | jk_down[2];

  jkff jkff0(clk, 1'b1, 1'b1, preset, clear, Q[0], Q_bar[0]);
  jkff jkff1(clk, jk[0], jk[0], preset, clear, Q[1], Q_bar[1]);
  jkff jkff2(clk, jk[1], jk[1], preset, clear, Q[2], Q_bar[2]);
  jkff jkff3(clk, jk[2], jk[2], preset, clear, Q[3], Q_bar[3]);
endmodule
```

jkff.v

```
module jkff(input clk, j, k, preset, clear, output q, q_bar);
  wire j_p, k_p, q_m, q_bar_m;

  assign j_p = !(j & q_bar & clk);
  assign k_p = !(k & q & clk);

  sr sr0(j_p, k_p, preset, clear, q_m, q_bar_m);
  gated_sr gsr0(!clk, q_m, q_bar_m, preset, clear, q, q_bar);
endmodule;
```

sr.v

```
//set, reset, preset, clear are active low
module sr(input set, reset, preset, clear, output q, q_bar);
  assign q = !(set & preset & q_bar);
  assign q_bar = !(reset & clear & q);
endmodule
```

gated_sr.v

```
//enable, set, and reset are active high; preset and clear are active low
module gated_sr(input enable, set, reset, preset, clear, output q, q_bar);
  wire set_p, reset_p;
  assign set_p = !(set & enable);
  assign reset_p = !(reset & enable);
  sr sr0 (
    .set (set_p),
    .reset (reset_p),
    .preset (preset),
    .clear (clear),
    .q (q),
    .q_bar (q_bar)
    );
endmodule
```

testbench code

```
`include "limited_ud_counter.v"
`include "../UpDownCounter/up_down_counter.v"
`include "../JKFF/jkff.v"
`include "../GatedSR/gated_sr.v"
`include "../SR/sr.v"

module limited_ud_counter_tb;
  reg clk, preset, clear, up;
  reg[3:0] limit;
  wire[3:0] Q;

  always begin
    #5 clk = !clk;
  end

  initial begin
    $dumpfile("limited_ud_counter_tb.vcd");
    $dumpvars;
  
    clk = 1'b0;
    up = 1'b1;
    preset = 1'b1;
    clear = 1'b0;
    limit = 4'b1100;
    #12 clear = 1'b1;
 
    #200 $finish;
  end

  limited_ud_counter ludc0(clk, preset, clear, up, limit, Q);

endmodule
```

This is using Icarus Verilog if that helps.

Comment: there is no code for 'up_down_counter' in your example. Apparently, the difference is that it is synchronized by clock and your code is not. your code is prone to glitches which could've caused the difference. But it is difficult to say without seeing the rest of the code.

Comment: The preset and clear inputs should be asynchronous for the jk flip flop's sr latches. However, I'll go ahead and post the rest of the code.

Comment: There are data races and glitches which can exist in simulation which could cause unexpected behavior. They are usually compensated with correct use of flops. You do not have even a single clock-driven flop but there are a lot of data-driven state devices and logically unneeded expressions. I suspect that glitches cause your differences. It is difficult to ping-point them at a glance. Some wave form viewers allow seeing them in waiveforms.  You can also debug your model using `always@* $display($time, value)`. It prints if the value has a glitch.  Try to debug your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out the issue. What was happening was while the values of preset_q and clear_q were being computed, there was a moment where both preset_q and clear_q went low. Since these were fed into SR-latches, an error would occur.

All at the same time (t=12), preset_q and clear_q went like this:

- preset_q = 1, clear_q = 0
- preset_q = 0, clear_q = 0 <- this is the problem
- preset_q = 1, clear_q = 1

Since these all happened at the same time, only the final values were visible on the waveform. To fix this, I chose to make both preset and clear signals go high if they were both low at the SR-latch level.

Comment: so, this was a glitch.